# Is your broker fee refunded when you cancel an order?

Tags: eve-online

There is a broker fee that's charged when you place a buy order. Is it refunded if/when you cancel the order? What if the order is partially completed when it's cancelled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
The broker fee is the price of creating the order.
The fee can be lowered with a skill, and/or by having high standings with the corp that owns the station that the order is created at, but it cannot be eliminated and it is never returned.